# how to use continue in switch case to go to the next case

Tags: php-7.3

When i try the continue in switch statement I am getting the warning as

> PHP Warning:  "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?

My code:

```
switch ($elements['type']){
    case test:
        if ($elements['score'] == 70)
            echo $elements['score'].PHP_EOL;
            continue;
        break;

    case test2:
        if ($elements['score'] == 90)
            echo $elements['score'].PHP_EOL;
            continue;
        break;

}
```

Comment: If you want to `continue` just delete the `break` and let `case test1: [code1]; case test2: [code2]`

Comment: its not working